# Why is my query using parallelism, even with MAXDOP = 0?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, parallelism

I'm having some headaches with a procedure.

Long story short, I'm using now a hint to force an index ( now, the query runs in 0.1 secs, after this, it was running in 2min )

but the question is, why is it using Parallelism, if it is set to 0?

[image]

[image]

Funny part is, when the query uses a different index, it does not use parallelism. Whe it uses this index ( IX_tbReps_cod_perito_primeiro_cod_status ), it uses parallelism.

For more information, the query:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GDLIC_REP_PARTS_SEARCH](
    @P_NUMBER               VARCHAR(23),
    @P_YEAR                      INT = NULL,
    @P_UNIT_COD             INT = NULL,
    @P_GENERIC_PARAM  VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @P_STATUS_COD           INT = NULL,
    @P_EXPERT_ID            INT = NULL,
    @P_PAGE_SIZE            INT = 10,
    @P_PAGE_INDEX           INT = 1
)AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED


    IF @P_NUMBER = '0' OR @P_NUMBER = '' SET @P_NUMBER = NULL   
    IF @P_YEAR = 0  SET @P_YEAR = NULL      
    IF @P_EXPERT_ID = 0 SET @P_EXPERT_ID = NULL 
    IF @P_STATUS_COD = -1 SET @P_STATUS_COD = NULL
    IF @P_UNIT_COD = 0  SET @P_UNIT_COD = NULL             
    IF (@P_GENERIC_PARAM = '0' OR @P_GENERIC_PARAM = '') SET @P_GENERIC_PARAM = NULL   
    IF (@P_PAGE_INDEX IS NULL) OR (@P_PAGE_INDEX = 0) SET @P_PAGE_INDEX = 1;         

    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TBP.COD_REP DESC) AS ITEM,       
        TBP.COD_PECA,
        TBP.COD_SEQ,
        TBP.COD_REP,
        TBP.NUMERO,
        TBP.ANO,
        TBP.COD_TIPOPECA,
        TBTP.TIPOPECA,
        TBP.IDENTIFICACAO,
        ISNULL(TBP.OBSERVACAO, '') as OBSERVACAO,
        TBP.QUANTIDADE_OLD,
        TBP.DATAAPREENSAO,
        TBP.LACREENTRADA,
        TBP.DATALIBERACAO,
        TBP.LACRESAIDA,
        TBP.CONSUMIDA,
        TBP.EXCLUIDA,
        TBP.TIPO,
        TBP.DESCRICAO,
        TBP.QUANTIDADE,
        TBP.DESCRICAO_QTD,
        TBP.ANALISE_CG,
        ISNULL(TBP.PLACA, '') as PLACA,
        ISNULL(TBP.CHASSI, '')as  CHASSI,
        TBP.N_SERIE,
        TBP.NANALISES,
        TBP.COD_ETPCT,
        TBP.RESULTADO,
        TBP.QUANT_ANALISADA,
        TBP.PESO,
        TBP.MODELO,
        TBP.COR,
        TBP.MARCA,
        TBP.ESTADOCONSERVACAO,
        TBP.CHASSISTATUS,
        TBP.PLACASTATUS,
        TBP.cod_morfologia,
        TBP.restante_material,
        TBP.descricao_resultado,
        ISNULL(TBM.nome, '') as DIMENSAO,
        TBP.objeto,
        M.descricao as des_droga_aparente,
        TBED.tipoent as des_droga_definitiva    
    INTO #TBTEMPPARTS 
    --FROM TBREPS REP WITH(NOLOCK)
    --Alteração feita por: DBA 
    --Data: 12-feb-2016
    FROM TBREPS REP WITH(nolock,index([IX_tbReps_cod_perito_primeiro_cod_status]))
    --
    JOIN TBPECAS TBP WITH(NOLOCK)  ON REP.COD_REP  = TBP.COD_REP
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LSTTIPOSPECA TBTP ON TBTP.COD_TIPOPECA  = TBP.COD_TIPOPECA
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LSTMEDIDAS TBM ON TBP.DESCRICAO_QTD = TBM.cod_medida 
    LEFT JOIN lstMorfologias M ON TBP.cod_morfologia = M.cod_morfologia 
    LEFT JOIN lstTipoEnt TBED ON TBP.cod_etpct = TBED.cod_tipoent          
    WHERE 
        1=1 
    AND (rep.numero =  @P_NUMBER OR @P_NUMBER IS NULL)
    AND (rep.ano = @P_YEAR OR @P_YEAR IS NULL)
    AND (rep.COD_PERITO_PRIMEIRO = @P_EXPERT_ID OR @P_EXPERT_ID IS NULL)
    AND (rep.cod_unidade = @P_UNIT_COD OR @P_UNIT_COD IS NULL)
    AND (rep.cod_status IN ( SELECT item FROM dbo.fnSplitInt(@P_GENERIC_PARAM, ',') ) OR @P_GENERIC_PARAM IS NULL)
    AND (rep.cod_status = @P_STATUS_COD OR @P_STATUS_COD IS NULL)
    ORDER BY TBP.COD_REP DESC


    SELECT
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TBTEMPPARTS) AS QTDE_REG,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By cod_rep Order By cod_rep) AS ROWNUM,
        #TBTEMPPARTS.*      
    FROM #TBTEMPPARTS
    WHERE ITEM BETWEEN (@P_PAGE_INDEX - 1) * @P_PAGE_SIZE AND @P_PAGE_INDEX * @P_PAGE_SIZE;


    SET NOCOUNT OFF;    

END
```

And the Index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tbReps_cod_perito_primeiro_cod_status] ON [dbo].[tbReps]
(
    [cod_perito_primeiro] ASC,
    [cod_status] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [data]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
 ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

There is this key lookup I can't fix but I will think about it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Setting maximum degree of parallelism to 0 allows SQL Server to use
>   all the available processors up to 64 processors.

Found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189094.aspx